# Wimax Dongle USB Modem is not working on Windows 8

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, wimax

After installing the drivers of WiMAX USB Dongle modem on Windows 8, it worked fine, but then suddenly it stopped connecting. So, I uninstalled the drivers. But on subsequent attempts to reinstall the same drivers I got a Device Driver install fail, tried several times but without success. How can I get my WiMAX device to work on Windows 8 PRO 64 bit edition?

Comment: I had the same problem with WU-216 WiMAX modem. It'd be helpful if you mentioned  your model number. AX-226 works fine though.

Comment: It's a Banglalion Wimax Modem(A wimaz Operator froM Bangladesh) , came with the connection